# Вывод файлов из архива

Tags: java, zip, вывод

Пытаюсь вывести имена файлов содержащихся в архиве, но выдаёт такую ошибку 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED

Что я делаю не так??

```
    String zipPath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\zzz.zip";
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipPath));

    ZipEntry entry;
    while((entry=zipInputStream.getNextEntry())!=null){
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
    }
```

Comment: код рабочий, проблема в архиве

Comment: Вероятнее всего, проблема с кодировкой. Уточните кодировку и при открытии потока укажите её